# Fourier transform of a measure (A qualifying exam problem from a UC, Help!!)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

here is a qualifying exam problem and my best attempt thus far:
(This is a previous problem, I'm not taking it right now.)

Problem: if $(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ is a finite Borel measure and $\phi(t)=\int e^{ixt}\,d\mu(x)$ is its Fourier transform if furthermore $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, prove that
$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^T|\phi(t)|^2\,dt\rightarrow 0$$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$.

My attempt is to write $$\int_{-T}^T|\phi(t)|^2\,dt=\int\int_{-T}^Te^{-itx}\phi(t)\,dt\,d\mu(x).$$

While the inversion theorem says that $$\int_a^b\int_{-T}^Te^{-itx}\phi(t)\,dt\,dx\rightarrow 2\pi\mu([a,b])$$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$ and somehow go from here. But I'm kind of stuck. Please help me!! Thanks!!

Oh, actually this follows from [An identity for Fourier transform of measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154881/an-identity-for-fourier-transform-of-measure)

Comment: For clarity, are you saying this is a question from a previous qualifying exam that you're attempting for practice?

Comment: Yes. I'm not taking the exam right now.

Comment: I am missing something, if you divide by $T$ then you get the result you desire?

Comment: @copper.hat    How do I get the result? The two equations are different. $dx$ means integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure. $d\mu(x)$ is integration with respect to the given measure.

Comment: Oh, actually this follows from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154881/an-identity-for-fourier-transform-of-measure

Comment: @MaoWao Yes. I have already noted this on Jun 29 in my question.

Comment: @Simplyorange I know. I just voted to close as duplicate, and this comment is automatically generated in this case. If I remember correctly, you can confirm this as a duplicate if you agree.